# Are dates on this question correct?

Tags: support

[Where are the Win 10 Quick Access settings stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/1051440/where-are-the-win-10-quick-access-settings-stored)

> asked Mar 11 at 5:34
>
> answered Mar 11 at 7:04
>
> edited Jul 16 at 17:34

A question about Windows 10 asked in 2011!? Minor edited in 2016, and couple of comments thereafter and also accepted as an answer. Or is it a glitch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's March 11th, not March 2011.  All those events occurred *this* year.

Questions that do not specify a year such as `Jul 30 '15` ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/947292/windows-10-rename-pinned-items-in-windows-explorers-quick-access?rq=1)) are assumed to be this year.

If you want to see the full date a question was asked in [ISO standard date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) you can hover your mouse over the time to see `2016-08-31 16:38:32Z` (the time you asked this question).

Related on [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/):

- [Date formatting on questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/date-formatting-on-questions-and-answers)